# Can I disable a VBA UDF calculation when the Insert Function/Function Arguments dialogs are displayed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA UDF that performs some expensive calculations.  Currently, Excel tries to run the function when the user clicks on the Insert Function dialog (the 'fx' button next to the formula bar), and this causes problems in my code.

Is there a way I can set the function to not calculate when the user has the Insert Function dialog (or the Function Arguments dialog, which is what shows up when the function name is already provided) open?  I'd like to have the function only run when the user enters the formula in a cell or refreshes the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this code to the start of your function:

```
If (Not Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls(1).Enabled) Then Exit Function
```

It will quit your UDF if the function wizard is being used

Comment: Thanks Charles. Works in Excel 2010. Had a question about why this works, but found the answer on your blog :). Is there a way to check the visibility of the wizard directly instead of checking if the standard controls are disabled?

Comment: You can alo use the Windows API to check if the Function Wizard window is showing and has the same process ID as the current Excel process, but checking the commandbars is MUCH easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is one circumstance in which the "CommandBars" solution provided by Charles Williams fails, falsely indicating that the function wizard is active when it's not.

It happens when you open a comma-separated text file in Excel in which case all open Excel workbooks are recalculated, even if Excel calculation is set to manual. That's quite disruptive if you have workbooks open with slow-to-calculate VBA UDFs that use the CommandBars test to exit early if the Wizard is thought to be active.

Charles further suggests that the Windows API can be used as an alternative approach. I've not been able to find such code elsewhere so here's my attempt to implement Charles' suggestion.

Tested only on English-language 64-bit Excel 365.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2


Function FunctionWizardActive() As Boolean

    Dim ExcelPID As Long
    Dim lhWndP As LongPtr
    Dim WindowTitle As String
    Dim WindowPID As Long
    Const FunctionWizardCaption = "Function Arguments" 'This won't work for non English-language Excel
    
    If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range" Then
        'The "CommandBars test" below is usually sufficient to determine that the Function Wizard is active,
        'but can sometimes give a false positive. Example: When a csv file is opened (via File Open) then all
        'active workbooks are calculated (even if calculation is set to manual!) with
        'Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls(1).Enabled being False
        'So apply a further test using Windows API to loop over all windows checking for a window with title "Function  Arguments", checking also the process id.
        If Not Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls(1).Enabled Then
            ExcelPID = GetCurrentProcessId()
            lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'PARENT WINDOW
            Do While lhWndP <> 0
                WindowTitle = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
                GetWindowText lhWndP, WindowTitle, Len(WindowTitle)
                WindowTitle = Left$(WindowTitle, Len(WindowTitle) - 1)
                If WindowTitle = FunctionWizardCaption Then
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId lhWndP, WindowPID
                    If WindowPID = ExcelPID Then
                        FunctionWizardActive = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
                lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
            Loop
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

With that function available, you can amend your slow VBA UDFs with the code:

```
If FunctionWizardActive() Then Exit Function
```