# Why my user function return VALUE! error and don't apply property?

Tags: vba

I have follow code:

```
Public Function myfunc()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Interior.Color = vbGreen
    myfunc = ""
End Function
```

**Why** when I type =myfunc() in cell B1 it is return #VALUE! error and don't fill A1 cell?

[image]

Also, **why** it make cell A1 green, when i press function icon?

[image]

Comment: A function called as a UDF from a worksheet cell can only return a value.

Comment: Workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet

Comment: Consequences - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52698777/11683

Comment: @GSerg - I think there's a some discussion in the linked question around "use at your own risk"...   There's a reason why it doesn't work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

A UDF in a cell can only return a value to the cell in which it resides.  It can't effect changes to other cells.  You need a `SUB` not a function.

Comment: so way why it is work, when i press function icon?

Comment: @WaleronTrot - seems like that function icon runs your function outside of the "worksheet calculation" sandbox.  It would also work if you called the function from a Sub instead.  See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866484/can-i-disable-a-vba-udf-calculation-when-the-insert-function-function-arguments